Creating javascript buttons in shinydashboard
I am trying to follow this excellent tutorial: https://thatdatatho.com/adding-action-buttons-in-rows-of-dt-data-table-in-r-shiny/ to add action buttons to a DT table in shinydashboard, but it appears that something in shinydashboard conflicts with the javascript and instead renders the buttons as html text instead of clickable action buttons.  Is there anyway to work around that conflict?
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinythemes)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  
  dashboardHeader(
    title="Test"
  ),
  dashboardSidebar(),

  dashboardBody(
    
    column(12,    
  
    
    box(
      title = "Available",
      status = "primary",
      solidHeader = TRUE,
      collapsible = TRUE,
      DTOutput("table1", height = "300px")
    ), # Close box
  
    fluidRow(

    box(
      title = "Current",
      status = "primary",
      background = "green",
      solidHeader = TRUE,
      collapsible = TRUE,
      DTOutput('table2')
    ), # Close box
    
    box(
      title = "Past",
      status = "primary",
      background = "red",
      solidHeader = TRUE,
      collapsible = TRUE,
      DTOutput('table3')
    ) # Close box
    ) # Close row
  )
  )# Close fluid row
) # Close UI


shiny::includeScript("script.js")


# Create button function
create_btns <- function(x) {
  x %>%
    purrr::map_chr(~
                     paste0(
                       '<div class = "btn-group">
                   <button class="btn btn-default action-button btn-info action_button" id="edit_',
                       .x, '" type="button" onclick=get_id(this.id)><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button>
                   <button class="btn btn-default action-button btn-danger action_button" id="delete_',
                       .x, '" type="button" onclick=get_id(this.id)><i class="fa fa-trash-alt"></i></button></div>'
                     ))
}

# Add buttons to the data frame

x = create_btns(1:32)
mtcars = mtcars  %>%
  dplyr::bind_cols(tibble("Buttons" = x))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  
  rv <- shiny::reactiveValues(
    df = mtcars,
    dt_row = NULL,
    add_or_edit = NULL,
    edit_button = NULL,
    keep_track_id = nrow(mtcars) + 1
  )
  

  output$table1 <- renderDT(mtcars, options =
                              list(scrollX = TRUE, pageLength = 25), editable = FALSE, rownames = FALSE)

  output$table2 = renderDT(mtcars, options =
                             list(scrollX = TRUE), editable = FALSE, rownames = FALSE)
  
  output$table3 = renderDT(mtcars, options =
                             list(scrollX = TRUE), editable = FALSE, rownames = FALSE)
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)


Provide a minimal, reproducible example of your app. script.js is not defined here.

In renderDT, add escape = FALSE:
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinythemes)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  
  dashboardHeader(
    title="Test"
  ),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  
  dashboardBody(
    
    column(12,    
           
           
           box(
             title = "Available",
             status = "primary",
             solidHeader = TRUE,
             collapsible = TRUE,
             DTOutput("table1", height = "300px")
           ), # Close box
           
           fluidRow(
             
             box(
               title = "Current",
               status = "primary",
               background = "green",
               solidHeader = TRUE,
               collapsible = TRUE,
               DTOutput('table2')
             ), # Close box
             
             box(
               title = "Past",
               status = "primary",
               background = "red",
               solidHeader = TRUE,
               collapsible = TRUE,
               DTOutput('table3')
             ) # Close box
           ) # Close row
    )
  )# Close fluid row
) # Close UI


# Create button function
create_btns <- function(x) {
  x %>%
    purrr::map_chr(~
                     paste0(
                       '<div class = "btn-group">
                   <button class="btn btn-default action-button btn-info action_button" id="edit_',
                       .x, '" type="button" onclick=get_id(this.id)><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button>
                   <button class="btn btn-default action-button btn-danger action_button" id="delete_',
                       .x, '" type="button" onclick=get_id(this.id)><i class="fa fa-trash-alt"></i></button></div>'
                     ))
}

# Add buttons to the data frame

x = create_btns(1:32)
mtcars = mtcars  %>%
  dplyr::bind_cols(tibble("Buttons" = x))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  rv <- shiny::reactiveValues(
    df = mtcars,
    dt_row = NULL,
    add_or_edit = NULL,
    edit_button = NULL,
    keep_track_id = nrow(mtcars) + 1
  )
  
  
  output$table1 <- renderDT(mtcars, options =
                              list(scrollX = TRUE, pageLength = 25), editable = FALSE, rownames = FALSE, escape = F)
  
  output$table2 = renderDT(mtcars, options =
                             list(scrollX = TRUE), editable = FALSE, rownames = FALSE, escape = F)
  
  output$table3 = renderDT(mtcars, options =
                             list(scrollX = TRUE), editable = FALSE, rownames = FALSE, escape = F)
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

